# How to check if a proxy server is working or not with PHP

Tags: php, proxy

I need help. 
I tried every single script on every Stackoverflow question related to my problem that I found, but nothing worked.

I want to check (with PHP) if a given proxy (ip:port) is working or is dead. Simple.

The script will work with HTTP GET requests, like

```
http://example.com/check.php?ip=1.2.3.4&port=567
```

And the response will be "Working" or "Dead".

At the moment my script is this:

```
$ip = $_GET["ip"]; 
$port = $_GET["port"]; 
$waitTimeoutInSeconds = 1; 
if($fp = fsockopen($ip,$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds)){   
   echo "Working";
} else {
   echo "Dead";
} 
fclose($fp);
```

But every ip and port I send to this script the response is always "Working". 
I tried every casual Ip and Port and the response is the same. 
The example above will return "Working" too.

I think there is a problem.

Why?

Comment: Your example doesn't work for me: "**Warning:** fsockopen(): unable to connect to 1.2.3.4:567 (Connection refused) Dead"

Comment: Noor for me, different error message though: `Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 1.2.3.4:567 (Connection timed out) -> Dead`

Comment: So why is not working for me? I'm trying with Postman app

Comment: If I can post my website (it's blank, only for testing things) this is my script hosted. When I load this link i read "Working".
http://ehzlab.altervista.org/webreaper/test.php?ip=1.2.3.4&port=567